# Upload a template file (Eg: home.php, home.html etc...) in views folder in codeigniter via file-upload

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have a CMS project in CodeIgniter. In admin panel have a form called add pages section where I need to upload a file to views folder i.e. root->Applications->views

Is it possible?

application
 - model
 - views (upload files here via coding)
 - controller

Comment: Why not.  Do you want add file in separate folder for admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be guided.

Controller:

```
public function sample(){
    $this-><Model_Name>->save_data($_POST,$_FILES);
}
```

Model:

```
public function save_data($data,$fetchFile){
    extract($data);
    $col_file = <name of the input type file>;
    $directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/<project_name>/application/views/";
    $file_name=$fetchFile[col_file]["name"];
    $file_tmp=$fetchFile[col_file]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$fetchFile[col_file]["tmp_name"],$directory.$file_name);
}
```